# cannot close node using blessed and gulp-live-server

Tags: node.js, terminal, gulp

I've a project that runs with Gulp and gulp-live-server (for starting app and restart on changes).

After implementing [blessed](https://github.com/chjj/blessed) in that project, I run in that issue that I cannot always close properly with `ctrl+c`.

Pressing `ctrl+c` twice without any changes made will close it (first closes the blessed dashboard and application, second gulp?).

Pressing `ctrl+c` twice with any changes made (and app has restarted) will only close the blessed dashboard and application. I cannot write nor press anything. The only solution is to close the tab.

When I run `top` there is `gulp` still running (no node).

This is what I've tried so far:

Gulpfile

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(0);
  }, 500);
});
```

Blessed screen

```
let exit = () => {
  process.exit();
};

this.screen.key(['escape', 'q', 'C-c'], () => {
  this.screen.destroy();
  exit();
});

process.on('SIGINT', exit);

process.on('SIGTERM', exit);
```

Any suggestions left that I can try?